# Is iterator the best way to loop through PriorityQueue

Tags: java, queue, priority-queue

I want to loop through a `PriorityQueue`, and wondering if following `iterator()` is the best way

```java
Iterator<MyObject> itr = queue.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext()){
  MyObject element = itr.next();
  // do sth
}
```

I suppose its time complexity would be O(1)?
I don't care about the queue afterwards, so another way would be to use `poll()` while `!queue.isEmpty()` but the time complexity would be O(logn).

Comment: Do you care about order?  iterator() won't give you any particular order.

Comment: I didn't realize that. yes I do care about order

Comment: @LouisWasserman I suppose stream also won't guarantee order then?

Comment: Correct. Streaming over a `PriorityQueue` will not guarantee order. In fact, the `Spliterator` returned by `PriorityQueue` does not report itself as `ORDERED`.

Comment: Fundamentally, the nature of priority queues as a data structure is that they only order themselves when elements are removed; they don't sort elements in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want ordered retrieval of your elements, you must poll/remove elements from the queue; using iterator will not be enough.